# Testing async function with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

We are facing an unexpected behavior while testing async code with Jasmine. As far as we know, when you are using the `done` function, expectations are not called until done is executed. But, that's not happening because the second expectation is failing, hence the `$ctrl.todos` assignment never happened

Not working test

```
it('initializes the data when $onIinit', (done) => {
  const expected = 'some result';
  const response = Promise.resolve(expected);

  spyOn(myService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(response);

  // This method calls myService.getAll
  $ctrl.$onInit();

  expect(myService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect($ctrl.todos).toEqual(false);

  response.then(done);
});
```

**Output: Expected undefined to equal false**

On the other hand, this is working:

```
it('initializes the data when $onIinit', (done) => {
    const expected = 'some result';
    const response = Promise.resolve(expected);

    spyOn(myService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(response);

    // This method calls myService.getAll
    $ctrl.$onInit();

    expect(myService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
    response
      .then(() => expect($ctrl.todos).toBe(expected))
      .then(done);
  });
```

**Output: test pass**

Controller method:

```
$ctrl.$onInit = () => {
  myService.getAll().then((data) => {
    $ctrl.todos = data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't really need another `then`. Specs with `done` will not complete until it's done is called. Also, it should be always placed after expectations.

**Working code:**

```
it('initializes the data when $onIinit', (done) => {
  const expected = 'some result';
  const response = Promise.resolve(expected);
  spyOn(myService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(response);
  $ctrl.$onInit();

  expect(myService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
  response
    .then(() => {
      expect($ctrl.todos).toBe(expected);
      done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your aproach seems to be correct, and probably calling `done` within `afterEach` will make it works.

```
afterEach(function(done) {
  done();
}, 1000);
```

But, I would recommend using [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), the fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for unit testing applications that use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). We are using `angularjs` anyway, right? So, why not take advantage of?

With [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) we can make the requests, then response with mock data without really sending the request to a real server. Here an ilustrative example

```
it('initializes the data when $onIinit', () => {
    const mockData = { data: { expected: 'some result' } };

    spyOn(myService, 'getAll').and.callThrough();

    $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/my-service/url').respond(200, mockData);

    // This method calls myService.getAll
    $ctrl.$onInit();

    //flush pending request
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(myService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($ctrl.todos).toBeDefined();
});
```

Some explanations, `$httpBackend.expect('POST', '/my-service/url')`, here note that `'POST'` need to match the `method` used by your service in `myService.getAll`, and `'/my-service/url'` is the `url` also used by your service in `myService.getAll`.

It is required to call `$httpBackend.flush();`, it will release all pending requests.

You will need to inject `$httpBackend` into your tests, an easy way would be

```
describe('$httpBackend service in module ngMock', () => {
    let $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(['$httpBackend', (_$httpBackend) => {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend;
    }]));

    it('$httpBackend is defined', () => {
        // here we can use $httpBackend
        expect($httpBackend).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Also, note that `$httpBackend` is part of the [ngMock](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngMock) module.

More info about testing angularjs code [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing)

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

`Promise` is from outside Angular world - you have to wait for result that will be available in next event queue tick - dirty (almost dirty) hack is to use `setTimeout`

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('underTest', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.$onInit = function() {
      myService.getAll().then(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data
      })
    }
  })

describe('Controller: somethingChanged', function() {
  var scope, myService

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('test')
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('myService', {
        getAll: function() {}
      })
    })
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _myService_) {
    myService = _myService_
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new()
    $controller('underTest', {
      $scope: scope
    })
  }))

  it('initializes the data when $onIinit', function(done) {
    const expected = 'some result'
    const response = Promise.resolve(expected)

    spyOn(myService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(response)

    scope.$onInit()

    expect(myService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();

    setTimeout(function() {
      expect(scope.todos).toEqual(expected)
      done()
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.6.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.6.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.6.1/boot.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.6.1/jasmine.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```